# How to connect GeoServer to a non-spatial database or Web service?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

We have a system built using an Oracle database with geographical informations (latitude/longitude) but **without spatial extensions** (Locator). We would like to connect a GeoServer to it in order to deliver WFS services (i.e. physical values measured at some coordinates).
Is it possible to adapt a GeoServer for such a database access?

Our system delivers also REST web services able to give this same latitude/longitude/value information.

Can GeoServer *translate* it to WFS service?

Comment: I suppose that you do not want to use Locator even it is free and would make working with GeoServer rather simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, years ago the DBA chose **not** to install Locator to this product. Since then all upgrades do not contain it, nor Oracle Multimedia, JAVAVM, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both by writing your own data store: 
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html

Once it's ready, drop its jar and eventual dependencies inside GeoServer own `WEB-INF/lib` directory, restart, and you'll be able to configure the store and use it (assuming it's properly implemented, of course)

For the Oracle with lat/lon columns, I would probably write a wrapper around an existing JDBC based store, transforming queries hitting the store to checks over the lat/lon columns based on the following classes:

- In order to alter styles, subclass [DuplicatingFilterVisitor](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/865cc72a90b07841a4c871d1b07fcc8e5defd35b/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/visitor/DuplicatingFilterVisitor.java)
- In order to split a filter in two parts, one that you can delegate, one that has to be run in memory, use either [PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/865cc72a90b07841a4c871d1b07fcc8e5defd35b/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/visitor/PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java) or [CapabilitiesFilterSplitter](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/865cc72a90b07841a4c871d1b07fcc8e5defd35b/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/visitor/CapabilitiesFilterSplitter.java)

In case coding is a problem, or you find the process hard, you can also check [commercial support](http://geoserver.org/support/)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for the Oracle database would be to use a [PostGIS foreign-data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/postgres-fdw.html), and then add the PostGIS table to GeoServer. I've no idea how slow that would be though.